# How to publish header files with template implementations?

Tags: c++, templates, header, software-distribution

We are creating a set of libraries with a public API which is to be used by different third parties. Some of the libraries are pure C so obviously they have a C styled header with functions and struct definitions and the corresponding library. They are ok.

Some of the libraries are written with the usage of a moderately complex C++ (targeting older compilers), so there we have implemented some form of the famous pimpl idiom. This is ok too.

On the other end a significant part of the header files is C++ using heavily templated code. Knowing [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) but also not willing to disclose too much implementation details to eyes who are not supposed to see them we have heavily refactored them to exclude as much internal details as possible and having only the really necessary bits... and there is still a significant amount of code left.

So it puzzles me: Is there a preferred way of distributing header files which largely contain templates? What good practices, best approaches and tips and tricks are there?

Comment: I don't think there's a robust treatment on this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Look at your C++ compiler's header files, for an inspiration. The standard C++ library is full of templates, and you will generally find all the template code in the headers.

Having said that, if particular templates are meant to be used with a small number of possible classes (or values) as template parameters, you do have an option of explicitly instantiating templates inside the library itself, leaving just the bare template declarations visible in the header files.

Using a simpler pre-C++11 scenario as an example, a C++ library will typically provide a `std::basic_string` implementation for only a `std::basic_string<char>` and `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`; and leave a bunch of template code inside the library itself, with just a bare `std::basic_string` template declaration visible in the header files.